# webkit mask cover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mask

I want to make a picture fade into whiteness. I have used a mask and gotten the desired effect http://jsfiddle.net/jspence29/8bDMp/ but the problem is I want to make the image cover the whole page(width I don't care about height), even when you resize the window. Something like background-size: cover; . But I can't do that because you can't put a mask into a background. And if I put 100% width into the html it just becomes too big for the screen. So I was wondering if there is anyway to fix this, javascript or jquery or something. Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<title> 
Singapore - gallery
</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">
<style>
*  {

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}
#background img {

  -webkit-mask-image: 
  -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
        from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), 
        to(rgba(0,0,0,0)))
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="background"> <img src="gallery.jpg" /></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the width to 100% works fine for me. add  `width: 100%;` to  `#background img`

http://jsfiddle.net/8bDMp/1/

Comment: Oddly enough, I put the width: 100%; after the mask inside that. So I guess that is what went wrong. I don't know why

Comment: You didn't have a ; after the gradient, so that's probably why it didn't work if you placed it after the gradient.